# Project fields in mongo Database Command with fulltext search

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to project fields in the result of a mongo fulltext search but so far with no luck. The comman is as this

> var textSearchCommand = new CommandDocument
>                {
>                    { "text", "mycollection" },
>                    { "search", keyword },
>                    {"project", "_id:1, Name:1"}
>                };

I've tried other approaches pro project but with no luck. What would be the correct syntax`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a BsonDocument for your `"project"` value instead of using a string:

```cs
var textSearchCommand = new CommandDocument
{ 
    { "text", "mycollection" }, 
    { "search", keyword }, 
    { "project", new BsonDocument { { "_id", 1 }, { "Name", 1 } } }
};
```